# Converting unevaluated lists to strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, hold

I have a list like

```
l = {2 - 3, 12 - 4, Times, aab}
```

I want to end up with

> {"2-3", "12-4", "Times", "aab"}

I have tried

```
lh = Map[ToString, HoldForm[l], {2}]
```

Which gives the promising result

> {ToString[2-3],ToString[12-4],ToString[Times],ToString[aab]}

However when I add `ReleaseHold` the numerical values get evaluated (*then* converted to strings).

```
ReleaseHold@lh
```

> {"-1", "8", "Times", "aab"}

How can I achieve the fully unevaluated string form?

This question may be a duplicate. If so, I apologise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ToString /@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@{2 - 3, 12 - 4, Times, aab}
```

or

```
HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@{2 - 3, 12 - 4, Times, aab} /. x_ :> ToString @ x
```

both give

```
 (* {"2 - 3", "12 - 4", "Times", "aab"} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

That might be the ugliest way to do it, but it works:

```
list = HoldForm@{2 - 3, 12 - 4, Times, aab};
string = ToString@list
listString = 
  StringSplit[StringReplace[string, {"{" -> "", "}" -> "", " " -> ""}], ","]
```

> {"2-3", "12-4", "Times", "aab"}

Then, `ToExpression /@ listString` yields:

> ```
> {-1, 8, Times, aab}
> ```

Comment: This doesn't work properly for cases such as `l = {Add[a, b], Mul[b, c]}`

Comment: It doesn't work if you have a comma indeed.